# Android startActivityForResult orientation change

Tags: android

I am using start activity for result to help users of my application filter some information out. Once the information is filtered i add it to the intent and then call finish. The works perfectly except for when the users have rotated the device when they are performing the filtering. This causes the first activity to create all over again and since this happens my filtering options are wiped out (They finish before onCreate is over so the UI is cleared). Any ideas on a way to handle this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 options to do this

1. `onSaveInstanceState()`  // But can usually handle small amount of data
2. `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() and getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` //Preferred
3. `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` in AndroidManifest.xml

// This will  not let the activity to get restarted, use this when the data you want to    conserve is not large.For api 13+ use this `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: Even when using android:configChanges there is still a possibility for activity recreation - there are other configuration changes possible.

Comment: Never ever use android:configChanges. It's baad af